# PHP Json response return the last row only

Tags: php, json

Hello i am trying to run this code lines with AngularJS but just get the last row of dataset, i have seen this example in a some sites, i don't know if i am missing some configuration:

```
$result = $mysqli->query ($query ) or die( $mysqli->error . __LINE__ );

$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $arr['data'] = $row;
    }
}

# JSON-encode the response
echo $json_response = json_encode($arr);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is just overwriting `$arr['data']` with the array `$row`:

```
$arr['data'] = $row;
```

Change it to

```
$arr['data'][] = $row;
```

and this will *push* the row, as an array, to `$arr['data']`.

Comment: thanks for your response, i change that line and get this result in console: Object {data: "", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}config: Objectdata: ""headers: (c)status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object, data is empty

Comment: Where in your code do you show output to console? Please include **all relevant code!**

Comment: I know it work because i have seen in tutorials, i don't know what is wrong in my case, i am using XAMPP

Comment: In a controler into app.js var data = {};
 
 SelEstados.getRequest( data ).then(
  function( result ) { // success
   console.log( result );
   console.log( result.data );   
   //$scope.estados = result.data;
  },
  function( result ) { // error
   console.log( result.data );
  }
 );

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, after a lot of tests, is a special characters management with json_encode